# Installing jazz 4.0.2 plugin with IBM Worklight 6 (juno eclipse) causes functional degradation in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rtc, worklight-studio

I've installed worklight 6 into an existing juno 64 bit eclipse running in windows 7.  Runs great.  I then install the jazz RTC 4.0.2 plug in into that eclipse environment.  After the plugin is installed, there is a noticeable loss of function.  The following are examples:

- On the create new Hybrid app page, the option for changing the dojo library used is gone.  The dialog resembles the WL5 version.
- after a dojo hybrid is created, the www folder is missing from the WL project
- Some dojo widgets do not work (i.e., not presented on the mobile device emulator or in resulting adroid application) like dojo.mobile.Heading

The only way to resolve is to uninstall the RTC plugin.  Any suggestion on how to make this work?  Using WL5.0.6.1 and same Jazz RTC plugin has no problems.  We want to move to newer WL and upgrading RTC is not an easy option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2? That's the only supported version for Worklight Studio (i.e. make sure you are not using 4.2.1 or 4.2 alone).

Other things I would try:
1) Use RTC 4.0.3 plug-in instead 4.0.2, that could make some difference and usually these clients have backwards compatibility with the server.

2) Install RTC before Worklight Studio, and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I verified that I am running 4.2.2 of eclipse.  I had already tried the installing of 4.0.3 RTC, but it is not backward compatible with 4.0.2 (https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/c_n-1.html&scope=null).  Apparently in RTC 4.0.3 they made it so it was not able to connect to anything older.  I'll try the order to see if that helps.

Comment: Genius.  The order is very specific.  Installing the RTC 4.0.2 into a vanilla eclipse 4.2.2 then adding worklight v6 and adt works.  Thanks